# Is there a programmatic way to know whether user is registered on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is there a programmatic ( using an email address) to know whether that person is registered on facebook or not?

I would like to give the user an option to post his details on his facebook page from my website. But I want to give him the option only if he/she has facebook profile. So I need a way of knowing this using email.

Comment: http://www.idolbin.com/blog/web-development/facebook/people-search-using-facebook-graph-api-find-users-through-name-or-email/ I know i havent answered your question but there was no point copying and pasting this entire article :)

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, Facebook will **not** share any information that **requires permission** publicly.

Just provide the functionality and let the user decides.